# Show 3 list items at a time and navigate one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show only 3 list item at a time and on clicking next and back button it will navigate to next/prev list items respectively.

[1,2,3]

Next button: [2,3,4]

prev button : [1,2,3]

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="myList">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
<li>Seven</li>
<li>Eight</li>
<li>Nine</li>
<li>Ten</li>
<li>Eleven</li>
<li>Twelve</li>
<li>Thirteen</li>
<li>Fourteen</li>
<li>Fifteen</li>
<li>Sixteen</li>
<li>Seventeen</li>
<li>Eighteen</li>
<li>Nineteen</li>
<li>Twenty one</li>
<li>Twenty two</li>
<li>Twenty three</li>
<li>Twenty four</li>
<li>Twenty five</li>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
size_li = $("#myList li").size();
x=3;
$('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
    $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
});
```

});

Code so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/q5j8fqx1/)

Comment: note that `size()` is deprecated...use `length` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach using one handler for both and using `slice()`.

```
var $items =  $("#myList li");
$items.filter(':lt(3)').show()

$('#loadMore, #showLess').click(function () {
    var more  = $(this).is('#loadMore'),
        first = $items.filter(':visible:first').index(),
        start = more ? ++first : --first;

    if(start > -1 && start <= $items.length - 3){
       $items.hide().slice(start, start+3).show();
    }
});
```

This will stop at both ends so always at least 3 visible. Will leave it to you to adjust button visibility/class as needed at the ends

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8fqx1/11/)

Comment: Thanks!! It works fine for me :) It is not showing first element(one), after navigating through showless

Comment: Try again...fixed that bug a while ago

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a range of elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x = 0;
    numToShow = 3;
    numToIncrement = 1;
    $('#myList').find('li').hide().slice(x, x + numToShow).show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x = (x + numToIncrement < size_li - numToShow + 1) ? x + numToIncrement : x;
        $('#myList').find('li').hide().slice(x, x + numToShow).show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x = (x - numToIncrement < 0) ? 0 : x - numToIncrement;
        $('#myList').find('li').hide().slice(x, x + numToShow).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8fqx1/13/

And what could be considered a more elegant solution using a single callback

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  x = 0, numToShow = 3, numToIncrement = 1;
  var $lis = $('#myList').find('li');
  $lis.slice(x, x + numToShow).show();
  $('#loadMore, #showLess').click(function() {
    x += 1 + $(this).is('#showLess') * -2;
    x = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), $lis.length - numToShow);
    $lis.hide().slice(x, x + numToShow).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
}
#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}
#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
  <li>Sixteen</li>
  <li>Seventeen</li>
  <li>Eighteen</li>
  <li>Nineteen</li>
  <li>Twenty one</li>
  <li>Twenty two</li>
  <li>Twenty three</li>
  <li>Twenty four</li>
  <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8fqx1/16/

Comment: This is not expected result :(

Comment: Only supposed to increment by 1 each time

Comment: Ahh yes, seems like I saw the wrong elements in his lists

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can make use of `.slice()` to show / hide `li`s. see below code and demo link

HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>

<div id="Previous">Load Previous</div>
<div id="Next">Show Next</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var start = 0;
    var end = 3;
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    $('#Previous').click(function () {
       if(start >0)
       {
           $("#myList li").hide();
           start = start - 1;
           end = end - 1;
           $("#myList li").slice(start, end).show();
       }

    });

    $('#Next').click(function () {
       if(end < size_li)
       {
           $("#myList li").hide();
           start = start + 1;
           end = end + 1;
           $("#myList li").slice(start, end).show();
       }
    });
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8fqx1/7/)**